# make new columns with for loop but i want to add ".Corr" to each name of these new columns in the loop. How can i do that?

Tags: r

these last three column are generated from the loop.
$PFN
         Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume  Adjusted    Return       HYG      TLT      SPY
1  2020-01-02 10.62 10.62 10.58 10.58  267700 10.231670        NA 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935
2  2020-01-03 10.59 10.69 10.58 10.68  351800 10.328378   0.94518 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935
3  2020-01-06 10.66 10.73 10.66 10.73  318400 10.376730   0.46816 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935
4  2020-01-07 10.71 10.76 10.70 10.71  261500 10.357388  -0.18639 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935

but i want to achieve this

$PFN
         Date  Open  High   Low Close  Volume  Adjusted    Return  HYG.Corr  TLT.Corr SPY.Corr
1  2020-01-02 10.62 10.62 10.58 10.58  267700 10.231670        NA 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935
2  2020-01-03 10.59 10.69 10.58 10.68  351800 10.328378   0.94518 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935
3  2020-01-06 10.66 10.73 10.66 10.73  318400 10.376730   0.46816 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935
4  2020-01-07 10.71 10.76 10.70 10.71  261500 10.357388  -0.18639 0.6840342 0.043489 0.656935

Everything should be done in for loop!

Comment: can you please show your code

Comment: Hello Vasil. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset objects are named 'PFN',  'PFP' etc, `get` the values of the objects, then rename those columns to preferred value and `assign` it back (not recommended to create multiple objects in global env).  It is better to have this in a `list`

```
objs <- c('PFN', 'PFP')
 for(obj in objs){
    tmp <- get(obj)
    nm1 <- c("HYG", "TLT", "SPY")
    names(tmp)[names(tmp) %in% nm1] <- paste0(nm1, ".Corr")
    assign(obj, tmp)
 }
```